# Mongoose .save() not working with no callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

When I execute the API http://localhost:8080/api/bears POST

the control gets mapped to post route and comes to .save() after which it doesn't return the 'err' callback.

I tried the global mongoose connection for two databases but no help.

**server.js**

```
// BASE SETUP
// =============================================================================

// call the packages we need
var express    = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app        = express();
var morgan     = require('morgan');

// configure app
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log requests to the console

// configure body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set our port

var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
//mongoose.connect('mongodb://node:node@novus.modulusmongo.net:27017/Iganiq8o'); // connect to our database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://zohaibusr:asd123@ds039115.mongolab.com:39115/zohaibdb'); // connect to our database

var Bear     = require('./app/models/bear');

// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================

// create our router
var router = express.Router();

// middleware to use for all requests
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // do logging
    console.log('Something is happening.');
    next();
});

// test route to make sure everything is working (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api)
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });   
});

// on routes that end in /bears
// ----------------------------------------------------
router.route('/bears')

    // create a bear (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/api/bears)
    .post(function(req, res) {

        var bear = new Bear();      // create a new instance of the Bear model
        bear.name = req.body.name;  // set the bears name (comes from the request)

        bear.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Bear created!' });
        });


    })

    // get all the bears (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api/bears)
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Bear.find(function(err, bears) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(bears);
        });
    });

// on routes that end in /bears/:bear_id
// ----------------------------------------------------
router.route('/bears/:bear_id')

    // get the bear with that id
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Bear.findById(req.params.bear_id, function(err, bear) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(bear);
        });
    })

    // update the bear with this id
    .put(function(req, res) {
        Bear.findById(req.params.bear_id, function(err, bear) {

            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            bear.name = req.body.name;
            bear.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                res.json({ message: 'Bear updated!' });
            });

        });
    })

    // delete the bear with this id
    .delete(function(req, res) {
        Bear.remove({
            _id: req.params.bear_id
        }, function(err, bear) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });
        });
    });


// REGISTER OUR ROUTES -------------------------------
app.use('/api', router);

// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

**Bear Schema**

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var BearSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear', BearSchema);
```

Edit : Adding screenshot

[image]

Comment: A side note here, don't just use `res.send(error)` but rather `res.status(500).send(err)`.

Comment: Ok thanks Will keep that in mind . However the control doesn't come to that line.

Comment: Are you sure that Mongoose can actually connect to the database?

Comment: Yes that is what even I am not sure of. Any idea how do i check? or any other public database available over

Comment: @Zohaib `mongoose.connection` is an event emitter that will emit [various events](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection-js). You can use it to check for connection errors.

Comment: @robertklep .. It was an issue with connection for mongodb..Check my answer.

Comment: Thanks everybody for prompt suggestions.Appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I figured out my mistake .

The connection established was wrong.

I was using a global mongo db for a quick start from mongolab.com

However after setting up on local. It worked

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/zohaibdb');

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Model.create`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) instead.

```
    Bear.create({name: req.body.name}, function(err, bear) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Bear created!' });
    });
```

Comment: Tried that, however the issue still persists the control doesnt come to the line if(err) .. and the call is still 'executing' ..

Comment: Please check screenshot attached